# How to set the path of appsetting.json file to DockerFile in IoT Edge Runtime Project

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile, azure-iot-edge

I created one IOT edge runtime custom module project on windows container.
While running the solution I am facing System cannot Find the file specified.
I am passing the values from appsetting.json file and while running the module the path is not getting specified.

Is it some way i can give some command to copy appsetting.json file in to container while building the image.

This is the Dockerfile i am using:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
COPY appsettings.json ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-1809
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project.dll"]
```

This is the cs.proj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|netcoreapp3.1|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <TreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectCapability Include="AzureIoTEdgeModule" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client" Version="1.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Loader" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="SasLib">
      <HintPath>lib\SasLib.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Resource\Resource.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resource.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resource\Resource.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resource.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Show us your csproj file content

Comment: I have added please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try specifying the folder in the Windows container where the appsettings.json file should be copied

```
COPY appsettings.json c:/temp/
```

Comment: Should i include it in dockerfile?

Comment: Here is the syntax of the command from the official site

`COPY test.txt /absoluteDir/`

maybe the dot before the directory does not need to be specified?

and
`The example below uses a relative path, and adds “test.txt” to <WORKDIR>/relativeDir/:

COPY test.txt relativeDir/
Whereas this example uses an absolute path, and adds “test.txt” to /absoluteDir/

COPY test.txt /absoluteDir/`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that appsettings.json is not copied to the output directory.
Try to add this into csproj file

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: @ArshitSingh not working why? any errors? incorrect behavior? could you please describe?

Comment: Thanks for your help Now its working i have added copy command in dockerfile.